# Why can the commutative rule be broken in quaternion algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hamiltons quaternion rule states that ij=k and ji=-k.  How can the commutative rule just be broken to make this true?

Comment: Quaternions did  not exist before they were invented by Hamilton. He *decided* that $ji=-ij$. As long as these rules do not lead to a contradiction, what can you say?

Comment: Commutativity is not automatically assumed in all algebras. It needs to be proven or axiomatically stated in order for it to hold.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative either.  Is that also broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Commutative rule" (as you call it) cannot be "broken," since it is a property that some operations have and some don't. Nothing here is "broken." Multiplication of quaternions is just not commutative (or, in other words, does not satisfy the commutative property).